# How to get ID node (key) from firebase realtime database on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, key

I have a firebase realtime database written like this:

```
"Users" : {
    "6SuuMBbymrV0YaiE82YCU8Qz0bj1" : {
      "Name" : "Vincent",
      "e-Mail" : "vinc.dl@gmail.com"
    }
```

And I want to get the ID (6SuuMBbymrV0YaiE82YCU8Qz0bj1) and put it in a string variable, so I can use it in a query interrogation (using where).
.Key and .Uid don't work, so how can I do it?

Comment: So you're saying you don't know what you're looking for, but you still want to find it?

Comment: I need to compare it to another value but first I have to retrieve it

Comment: Before you retrieve it, you have to know its key, or at least something about it.  Either that, or you request the entire database and figure it out somehow.

Comment: That's what I want, get the node key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, We will create Firebase Client using FirebaseDatabase.net package.

```
FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("Firebase Database URL");
```

**User Model**

```
public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string e-Mail { get; set; }

        public string Key { get; set; } //To Store ID
    }
```

**Firebase Query to get users**

```
await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User
              {
                  Key = item.Key, // This is the ID
                  Name = item.Object.Name,
                  e-Mail = item.Object.e-Mail
              }).ToList();
```